# Break one line of "if else" statement into multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, pep8

I want to break this code:

```
ex = func(object) if not self.is_object() else foo()
```

to multiple lines (pep 8).
What is the best way to do it?
I thought about this:

```
ex = func(object) \
    if not self.is_object() \
    else foo()
```

But this seems a bit ugly and not very neat. Is there another way?

Edit: This is different from just breaking a line into multiple lines, because this is a special "expression if stmnt else stmnt" and not just breaking any python code.

Comment: It's not that special; it's just a ternary operator `... if ... else ...` as opposed to a binary operator `... + ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly is ugly here? Backslashes? There's a way to avoid them
To split a statement into multiple lines, use parentheses around the conditional like so:

```
ex = (func(object)
      if not self.is_object()
      else foo())
```

But perhaps it would be better to write an entire conditional structure:

```
if not self.is_object():
    ex = func(object)
else:
    ex = foo()
```

Comment: I think you're right. I'll just stay in the regular way. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to break that into multiple lines is as follows:

```
if not self.is_object():
    ex = func(object)
else:
    ex = foo()
```

If you don't need it to be contained in a single expression, you might as well use a traditional `if..else` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must avoid the ternary expression (many people seem to dislike them) the canonical method would be neater:

```
if self.is_object():
    ex = foo()
else:
    ex = func(object)
```

which has the advantage that any Python programmer can read it without wondering what on Earth is going on!

Answer (score 0):

Might be best to break it into an if statement if it doesn't fit onto one line:

```
if self.is_object():
    ex = foo()
else:
    ex = func(object)
```

Or you can use parentheses:

```
ex = (func(object)
       if not self.is_object()
       else foo())
```